# WP survey plugin for tree structure questions

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin available in wordpress for a survey in which each next question is based on the answer of previous question.

For Example:

Q1:Do you like burger? 
Answer: Yes 
Q2: Which burger?

If answer to Q1 is No then,
Q2: Do you like pizza?

I need this kind of plugin, extension or something.

Comment: thanks @Louis i dont need a free one i will purchase just tell me any good plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There Are lots of plugin for this.

I know about some of plugin.

Form craft - Use condition logic.

Free version-> 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/formcraft-form-builder/

Pro version ->
http://codecanyon.net/item/formcraft-premium-wordpress-form-builder/full_screen_preview/5335056

Check demo
http://formcraft-wp.com/demo/form-view/6327?preview=true

I have used form craft pro and i know you can make as per your requirements using it

About some free plugin check this but i have not test it. http://masterblogster.com/5-best-conditional-logic-form-plugins-wordpress/

Suggestions - You can also make your own custom plugin too. which is best. but little time consuming.

Comment: thanks Form craft works for me. I want to confirm that can i do that same thing with this free formcraft builder also? or i have to purchase ?

Comment: I just checked free version its not come with condition logic. so you need to purchase it.

Comment: I purchased it. I dont know how to set up a conditional survey and I cant find the documentation any where about this. Can you help?

Comment: I tried making this http://formcraft-wp.com/demo/wp-admin/admin.php?page=formcraft3_dashboard&id=6330 but my conditions not working

Comment: you can find doc from here. http://formcraft-wp.com/help/how-to-use-conditional-logic/

first try it. if not then i will help

Comment: This is exactly how I made it. I also took help from demo they already made but my conditions are not working. as i shared the link with you.

Comment: Okay check. what i have try on your demo form. and its working fine for me

Comment: don't remember your mistake. but i am sure you may go with this. its easy. and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107919/discussion-between-rida-mukhtar-and-jitendra-it).